# Formatting text while typing in a Tkinter Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, text-widget

I'm trying to add notes to a given text that's not to be altered. It's pretty much like formatting in common text editors.

I have tried to get the current cursor position via `.index('insert')`, and then  tag the character either forwards with `tag_add(current cursor, current cursor '+1c')`, or backwards with `tag_add(current cursor + '-1c', current cursor)`. This results in  tagging either the character right before or after the character just typed.

Are there any workarounds to live-tag the actually typed character?

```
import tkinter


main = tkinter.Tk()

def typing(event):
    text.tag_configure('note', background='yellow')
    text.tag_configure('note2', background='blue')
    cur_cursor = text.index("insert")
    text.tag_add('note', cur_cursor + '-1c', cur_cursor)
    text.tag_add('note2', cur_cursor, cur_cursor + '+1c')

text = tkinter.Text(main)
text.grid()
text.bind('<Key>', typing)

for i in ['OX'*20 + '\n' for i in range(10)]:
    text.insert('end', i)

main.mainloop()
```

Edit: Although Bryan's answer worked for me you might get problems  with fast typing as described here: [how-to-get-cursor-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798254/python-how-to-get-cursor-position-in-tkinter-text-widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to bind on `<KeyRelease>` rather than `<Key>`. The reason is that the text widget doesn't actually insert the character you typed until its own `<Key>` binding fires, and that binding always fires *after* any custom bindings you have on the widget.

Comment: This does not work if the key is held down and there is a visible delay between key press and formatting. Is there any workaround for this?